# findFragmentByTag for viewPagers fragments always returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to retrive a `Fragment` at `position 0` from my `ViewPager` and I think I have done everything right, but I still get a `NullPointerException`

**In my `MainActivity` I try to retrive the `Fragment` with the code:**

```
GaitDistribution gaitDistribution = (GaitDistribution) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.topPager + ":" + 0);
```

A quick look into the `FragmentPagerAdapater` class tells us that the adapter makes fragment tags for each fragment it holds this way:

```
private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
}
```

The `viewID` parameter is `R.id.topPager`, but anyway I still tried to see what is really passed as the `viewId`, so I tried this in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Log.d("TAG", container.getId() + " pos: " + position);
    return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
}
```

And the Logcat gave me: `2131493099`  as the `viewId`, and put that integer in the tag string instead of `R.id.topPager` without any success!

**The ViewPager Adapter:**

```
public class MyHorseViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final int NUMofPages = 3;
    private int walkProgess, canterProgress, trotProgress;
    private int duration;
    private boolean isSound, isVibrate;

    public MyHorseViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int walkProgess, int canterProgress, int trotProgress, int duration, boolean isSound, boolean isVibrate) {
        super(fm);
        this.walkProgess = walkProgess;
        this.canterProgress = canterProgress;
        this.trotProgress = trotProgress;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.isSound = isSound;
        this.isVibrate = isVibrate;
    }

    public MyHorseViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                GaitDistribution gaitDistribution = GaitDistribution.newInstance(walkProgess, trotProgress, canterProgress, isSound, isVibrate, duration);
                return gaitDistribution;
            case 1:
                Intensity intensity = new Intensity();
                intensity.setRetainInstance(true);
                return intensity;
            case 2:
                Stats stats = new Stats();
                return stats;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUMofPages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the Fragment at a certain position?

Comment: Where did you add the `Fragment` to the `ViewPager`? Please add that code.

Comment: You shouldn't Override private methods.

Comment: @MuratK. Yes I want fragment at position 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve a Fragment from a ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager)

Comment: Use an array and store the fragments there. The index is the position

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have just done it¨

Comment: @MuratK. I will try the link and give an answer if it works

Comment: @MuratK keeping references to all the fragments in the viewpager is very expensive memory wise